# Dynamic deserialize JSON from method

Tags: json, model-view-controller, serialization

How to dynamic deserialize JSON from method in controller? I use that code:

```
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(GetReservedDaysJson().ToString());
```

And have that error:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: M. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

My JSON from GetReservedDaysJson() function look like that:

```
["2022-03-29","2022-03-30"]
```

Unless someone has a better solution. It needs to compare each date with JSON. With the date provided in the model.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
string json = GetReservedDaysJson();
List<DateTime> dates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DateTime>>(json);
```